# Groovy Script and C# Integration

Tags: c#, groovy, integration

We have a console application running in C#, and we need to integrate a groovy script with that. Is there a way to do that? Of course I google it before coming here, and the only useful result I got, it was this one here below:

https://jnbridge.com/blog/groovy-to-net-integration

But we need to use C#, not any external libraries. So, basically what we need a way to integrate a groovy script in our C# code.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you expect from integration? Why it's not just running groovy command line from your code?

Comment: This script has to be triggered automatically when the user follow some procedures. Unfortunately, I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at IKVM.NET I do think this is what you are wanting, "IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework. IKVM is free software, distributed under a permissive free software license."  this allows usage of java to C# bridge and vice versa.

Comment: Project is closed since 2017

Comment: there are forks of it,  https://github.com/jessielesbian/ikvm